# Create Exclude() extension method for IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework in my project. In some cases I need to get all the columns from the row, and some cases I need to get all the columns besides a specific in order to optimize speed and avoid querying a lot of data.

For example lets say that I am saving emails in a table and I have the columns: "From", "To", "Subject", "Content". Sometimes all I need is:

```
context.Emails.ToList();
```

and sometimes I need to exclude the content because is to big and I dont need it:

```
context.Emails.Select(e=>new Email {
                         From=e.From,
                         To=e.To,
                         Subject=e.Subject,
                    }).ToList();
```

I am aware that I can use this .Select solution, but is kind of annoying to map all the object every time. I am also aware that I can split the data in 2 tables creating 1:1 relationship, but I dont like this solution so much.
Anyway, I want to create a solution like this:

```
context.Emails.Exclude(e=>e.Content).ToList();
```

Basically I was thinking on doing a extension method like this:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<TSource> Exclude<TSource, TExclude>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TExclude>> selector)
        {
            return source.Select(a =>
            {
                var obj = (TSource)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TSource));
                foreach (var item in typeof(TSource).GetProperties())
                {
                    if (item!=typeof(TExclude))
                    {
                         item.SetValue(obj, item.GetValue(a));
                    }                    
                 }
                return obj;
            });  
        }
    }
```

I think this could be a potential good solution if we were dealing with IEnumerable, but since we are dealing with IQueryable this doesnt work.

I basically want to automate the mapping for the .Select() on IQueryable ignoring a specific property

Anyone has any idea of how can I make this works?

Comment: You can add a custom boolean property to your Email entity something like "ToExclude" and then you can simply filter based on that value.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your solution @RavirajPalvankar . Again: I want to filter columns and not rows

Comment: The recommended way to do it is to map using Select. If it's always the Content column you want to exclude, I'd make a method in my repository that returns the data without Content. If it's different columns you want to exclude, then I'd probably write a Select on all the queries. Sure it's a bit annoying, but it's readable and maintainable.

Comment: Meanwhile I am using Select() in some cases and 1:1 relationship in other cases... But the select solution is too annoying and I want to automate this mapping by an extension method . After all, working to be lazy is what we programmers do, right?!

Comment: @MichaelRandall you are saying that AutoMapper can return IQueryable?

Comment: @juanora good point, anyway i just wanted to have a dig at automapper

Comment: Problem is `Select` needs a return type. You want type that has one less property that original, but you cannot easily generate types at runtime. And even if you generate type at runtime - it won't be known at compile time, so you will have to return `object` back to the caller. And what that caller will do with that `object`? Not much useful.

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify the fieldnames in the `Select` - they will be inferred.

Comment: Apparently the best way to make this work is to map the table to two different entities and setup an associate between them or switch between them when you need all the data. Here is an article on using an association: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/09/01/splitting-tables.aspx

Comment: If you only need ReadOnly access to these fields, you might be able to create a sql view that only returns you the columns you need and include that in your model.

Comment: Maybe just rehash of what others have said, but the way I have addressed this is using DTOs and Automapper. Create a DTO with the properties you want, and have Automapper take care of the mapping. It's an interesting problem, and I'm curious of a real answer to your question, though.

Comment: @NetMage I am aware of the 1:1 table relationship solution. You are right regarding not specifying the filednames in the Select

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett I use the way you describe or 1:1 sql relationship depending the case... But Im curious if there is someway to just change the query generated by IQueryable

Comment: @juanora The answer is yes, you could dynamically create an anonymous type and create an `Expression` dynamically and pass it to `Select`, but the type returned would be `object` and the end result would be of questionable usefulness.